# Problem with types only being known at run-time causing DI pains

Tags: c#, structuremap

I'll explain my problem with an example.

I have an AnimalService, allowing me to increase the amount of show time the favourite animal gets for a specific zoo:

```
public sealed class AnimalService<TZoo> : IAnimalService<TZoo> where TZoo : IZoo
{
    private readonly IFavouriteAnimalResolver<TZoo> favouriteAnimalResolver;
    private readonly IAnimalShowTimeService animalShowTimeService;

    public AnimalService(
            IFavouriteAnimalResolver<TZoo> favouriteAnimalResolver, 
            IAnimalShowTimeService animalShowTimeService)
    {
        this.favouriteAnimalResolver = favouriteAnimalResolver;
        this.animalShowTimeService = animalShowTimeService;
    }

    public void IncreaseShowTimeForFavouriteAnimal(TZoo zoo)
    {
        var favouriteAnimal = favouriteAnimalResolver.GetFavouriteAnimal(zoo);

        animalShowTimeService.IncreaseShowTimeForAnimal(favouriteAnimal);
    }
}
```

The AnimalService uses a resolver to get the favourite animal for TZoo, and then it calls an instance of IAnimalShowTimeService to increase the amount of show time the favourite animal will get. Below is the definition of the IFavouriteAnimalResolver interface and implementation of it that allows me to resolve the favourite animal for LondonZoo:

```
public interface IFavouriteAnimalResolver<TZoo> where TZoo : IZoo
{
    IAnimal GetFavouriteAnimal(TZoo londonZoo);
}

public class LondonZooFavouriteAnimalResolver : IFavouriteAnimalResolver<LondonZoo>
{
    public IAnimal GetFavouriteAnimal(LondonZoo londonZoo)
    {
        return new Lion();
    }
}
```

Oki, so all good so far.  Now for the complication.  I would like to perform some animal specific logic once the IncreaseShowTimeForFavouriteAnimal is run.  So my base AnimalShowTimeService stub looks like this:

```
public class AnimalShowTimeService : IAnimalShowTimeService
{
    public void IncreaseShowTimeForAnimal(IAnimal animal)
    {
        // Update the show time for the animal

        // Now call out to the AnimalUpdatedService<> instance to do any logic required for the animal
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to call an update service that will get resolved via structuremap for the specific animal type, so I can run some update logic related to that specific type of animal.  I have the following animalupdated interfaces for this purpose:

```
public interface IAnimalUpdatedService<T> where T : IAnimal
{
    void LogTheUpdate(T animal);
}

public class DefaultAnimalUpdatedService<T> : IAnimalUpdatedService, IAnimalUpdatedService<T> where T : IAnimal
{
    public void LogTheUpdate(T animal)
    {

    }
}

public class LionUpdatedService : IAnimalUpdatedService<Lion>
{
    public void LogTheUpdate(Lion animal)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The lion was updated");
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have a DefaultAnimalUpdatedService which I want to be used when no specific update service was registered for an animal.  I also have a LionUpdatedService which I would like to use every time a Lion's show time was increased for a zoo.

My problem is that because the favourite animal for a zoo can be any animal, the IFavouriteAnimalResolver returns an IAnimal type back and not a concrete.  So I am not sure how I can use structuremap within IncreaseShowTimeForAnimal to get the LionUpdatedService service when a Lion's show time has been updated.  I have played around with following code, but this won't work because I don't know the concrete at design time:

```
    public class AnimalShowTimeService : IAnimalShowTimeService
{
    public void IncreaseShowTimeForAnimal(IAnimal animal)
    {
        // Update the show time for the animal

        var animalUpdatedService = ObjectFactory.ForGenericType(typeof(IAnimalUpdatedService<>))
                                                .WithParameters(animal.GetType())
                                                .GetInstanceAs<IDONTKNOWTHECONCRETE>();

        animalUpdatedService.LogTheUpdate(animal);
    }
}
```

I hope this all is clear.  :)

I am not very well versed in StrutureMap, so would appreciate if anyone knows of an elegant way to approach this problem.

I have zipped up a test project I created using the above described code.  You can download it here if you want to have a quick environment to fool around in:
[removed this link - no longer needed]

**EDIT:**

This is just a test project I created to illustrate the problem I am currently having in a much larger and more complex project.  Unfortunately I can't redesign the entire architecture of the project to find a better design more geared towards this solution as I simply don't have the time.  Being able to get the structuremap call simply return the correct concrete based on requirements above would be my immediate win.  Learning about a better design to ensure things like this don't happen to me again would be a secondary win.

Thanks people :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oki, I have got a solution for my problem. Namely, the Visitor pattern.  :-)

Quick reference: [The Visitor Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/visitor-pattern.html)

So I define a show time updated visitor, which can contain logic for each specific animal type:

```
public interface IShowTimeUpdatedVisitor
{
    void Visit(Lion lion);
    void Visit(Elephant lion);
    void Visit(IAnimal animal);
}

public class ShowTimeUpdatedVisitor : IShowTimeUpdatedVisitor
{
    public void Visit(Lion lion)
    {
        //do stuff with a lion
    }

    public void Visit(Elephant elephant)
    {
        //do stuff with an elephant
    }

    public void Visit(IAnimal animal)
    {
        // this will be the default which will be hit if no Visit method for the concrete exists
    }
}
```

Then I have made modifications to the IAnimal interface to allow each implementation to call the correct method against ShowTimeUpdatedVisitor:

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    void ShowTimeUpdated(IShowTimeUpdatedVisitor updatedVisitor);
}

public class Lion : IAnimal
{
    public void ShowTimeUpdated(IShowTimeUpdatedVisitor updatedVisitor)
    {
        updatedVisitor.Visit(this);
    }
}
```

Now, I can implement my AnimalShowTime service like this:

```
public class AnimalShowTimeService : IAnimalShowTimeService
{
    readonly IShowTimeUpdatedVisitor showTimeUpdatedVisitor;

    public AnimalShowTimeService(
            IShowTimeUpdatedVisitor showTimeUpdatedVisitor)
    {
        this.showTimeUpdatedVisitor = showTimeUpdatedVisitor;
    }

    public void IncreaseShowTimeForAnimal(IAnimal animal)
    {
        animal.ShowTimeUpdated(showTimeUpdatedVisitor);
    }
}
```

So in the end I didn't have to do any messy StructureMap code.  :)

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

a) Following the principle of "Tell, don't ask", it is not the AnimalShowTimeService's reposibility to resolve the type. Push the Animal to another object to make the choice.

b) Hardcoding references to ObjectFactory inside your domain is a bad design. The purpose of a DI container is to decouple your objects, not move the coupling somewhere else (StructureMap in this case).

Edit:

With regards to a) don't solve it in a polymorphic manner. You don't need generics to share behaviour, and inheritance hierachies only increase coupling. If you really do need to go down this path, I think implementing your own Convention might be what you're looking for. Or you could name every instance of IAmimal, and resolve the service with ObjectFactory.GetInstance(animal.GetType().ToString()), but that is clearly not ideal.

I think the point is however, that you're doing this as an exercise for DI & DI containers (I think), and if you can't get your design to fit, maybe you need to scrap it and start again, rather than trying to force a square peg into a round hole.

Comment: I agree with you on both.

For your suggestions though, my responses:

a) Yes, sounds like a perfectly reasonable suggestion, but my problem still stands.  How would I resolve this type?

b) Completely agree, I just feel like I am forced into this at the moment, because I can't create a generic AnimalShowTimeService<T> to get a better design here as I don't know the types till runtime.

I appreciate that I am wrong, but do you perhaps have a more practical example of how I might solve my problem?

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't an exercise on DI :(.  I simply created this example to more clearly illustrate my problem, as the domain language  implementation of this problem in the project I am currently working on may be confusing. I wish I could just scrap everything and redesign it. :(  This need for update monitoring to specific types only came up recently.   I can't afford to redesign the entire base right now.  Even if I am forced to still maintain the 'ObjectFactory.GetInstance' call directly in my code I need to do this. I will experiment with the named instances method for now.  Thanks.